# not all arguments converted during string formatting when assign values

Tags: python, api, openstack

I have a define to create network via network openstack api:

```
def CreateNetwork(self, course_id, network_name, subnets):
    data = {'network' : {'name' : utils.NET_NAME % (course_id, network_name), 
                             'admin_state_up' : True}}
   netw = self.neutron.create_network(body = data)
   net_dict = netw['network']
   network_id = net_dict['id']

        #Create subnets
   subnet_data = {'subnets' : []}
   subnet_data['subnets'].append({'cidr' : subnets,
                                   'ip_version' : 4,
                                   'network_id' : network_id})
   self.neutron.create_subnet(body = subnet_data)                     
   return network_id
```

And I assign values:

```
network = net.CreateNetwork(course_id = course.id, network_name = name, subnets = subnet)
```

then I receive error:

```
 "network = net.CreateNetwork(course_id = course.id, network_name = name, subnets = subnet)
 File "/web/lab/*****b/cnetworks.py", line 114, in CreateNetwork
 data = {'network' : {'name' : utils.NET_NAME % (course_id, network_name),
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

Please teach me how to fix this. tks

Comment: What is the value of `utils.NET_NAME`?

Comment: in utils.py I define a prefix NET_NAME and now a want to mix that prefix with network_name and subnets

Comment: Edit question with `utils.NET_NAME` so we can see how the string is formatted

Comment: NET_NAME = PREFIX_NETWORKNAME + '-%s'

Comment: OK, so what is the value of PREFIX_NETWORKNAME? Does it contain a `%` placeholder? Easiest way to check is to `print(utils.NET_NAME)` and add its value to your question.

Comment: PREFIX_NETWORKNAME = 'n'. now i know what i missing. the correct should NET_NAME = PREFIX_NETWORKNAME + '-%s-%s'

Comment: @mhawke : now I have another error when I call define:
   'def AddPort(self, router_id, network_id, port):
        server_detail = router_id
        if server_detail != None:
            body_value = {'port' : {'admin_state_up' : True,
                                        'device_id' : router_id,
                                       'name' : 'port{0}'.format(port),
                                       'network_id' : network_id}}
            response = self.neutron.create_port(body = body_value)
        return response
i get error:
OverQuotaClient: Quota exceeded for resources: ['port']'

Comment: @VuHiep: another problem means asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have `%s` which expects a string. But, `course.id` looks to be an integer in which case you need `%d`. This is assuming of course that `PREFIX_NETWORKNAME` contains another `%s` to format the network name. So you're string would be of the format `..%d...%s`. If `course.id` is an integer. If it's not an int but a string you need `..%s...%s..` Otherwise you can't format the two values into this string.